# How to authenticate user when testing REST API using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to make a script to test REST services using Jmeter.
Till now I was using Chrome’s Advanced REST Client.
My authentication request was GET and it was something like this in Advanced REST:
https://username:password@URL:portnumber
its a GET request

Now when I am using Jmeter. I tried following ways:
I added HTTP Authorization Manager and mentioned Base URL and Username/password inside it.
When I am trying to do a request then its showing me “Unauthorized”

I also tried to login using normal https request but no success.

When accessed manually, a authorization popup window appears and username and password is submitted inside this window.

Please suggest me a way for how to login using Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:

1. Most likely you have mismatch in URL you're trying hit and the one, specified in HTTP Authorization Manager, double check it.
2. Add View Results Tree listener and make sure that the header like:

   ```
   Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx=
   ```

   is being sent along with the request and compare it with the one, sent by the real browser.
3. Try switching "Implementation" of your HTTP Request samplers to HttpClient3.1, the easiest way of doing this is using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults)
4. And finally, you can use [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send the relevant header, it's name should be `Authorization` and value `Basic` and `username:password` encoded in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). There is [base64Encode](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) function available via JMeter Plugins.